# Quando faço um push para o git, caracteres com acentos "bugam". Como resolver?

Tags: java, git, github

Tenho um projeto em Java, e, por exemplo: Digito em alguma linha do meu código "Não definido", quando faço um push para o git fica "N�o definido" ou algo pior. Tem como evitar isso em alguma configuração do git, ou na minha própria aplicação Java ? Uma vez eu ouvir falar sobre algo do tipo Locale em Java, só que não lembro mais como funciona, se vai resolver o problema ou como implementa. OBS: Uso GitHub e faço os Push pela IDE Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Esse caracter normalmente significa inválido, ou seja, você está com problema de encode.

Verifique a configuração de encode na sua IDE Eclipse, pois ela não está conseguindo interpretar o encode dos arquivos que você está guardando no Git.

Comment: O encode já está como UTF-8

Comment: Estar com UTF-8 não quer dizer que não vá dar problema! A questão é: se você está salvando em UTF-8, não está "lendo" no mesmo formato.

1 - Verifique a instalação do Git.
2 - Tente criar um repositório novo e fazer a adição de um arquivo com o bloco de notas, por exemplo, e teste se dá o mesmo problema